# QGraphicsSimpleText - set anchor/alignment?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicssimpletextitem

I have added simpleText above my rectangleItem in my view. As I zoom in/out the text resizes up/down to remain readable. However, it resizes from top left corner to bottom right corner of the text. So the text eventually goes over my rectItem.

Does any1 have any suggestions how to anchor/align the text to be resized from bottom left to upper right?

I call `self.text.setFont(QFont("Arial",newSize)` to resize my text.

Thanks!

Edit1 :

I made a rough sample code to show the issue - it wont run...but you can see that when text gets expanded then it will go over its parent item :

The 2 functions below go together

```
class mySimpleText(QGraphicsSimpleTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(mySimpleText,self).__init__(self,parent=parent)
        self.setText("HEY SEXY")
        #self.setPlainText("HEY SEXYYY") # using TextItem


class mySpecialRect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self,myManager,rect):
        super(mySpecialRect,self).__init__(self,rect)
        self.myManager = myManager
        self.myTextLabel = mySimpleText(self)
        self.myTextLabel.setPos(self.boundingRect().x()-50,self.boundingRect().y())
        self.initSignals()
    def initSignals(self):
        self.myManager.userFontChanged.connect(self.fontChanged)


    def fontChanged(self,size):
        self.myTextLabel.setFont(QFont("Arial",size))
```

This is my class that send signal :

```
class myView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self,myManager):
        super(myView,self).__init__(self)
        self._font_Size = 10
        self.myManager = myManager
        pass # some init functions

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        scenePosition = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        inFactor = 1.25
        outFactor = 1 / inFactor
        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = inFactor
            self._font_Size = self._font_Size - 10
        else:
            self._font_Size = self._font_Size + 10
            zoomFactor = outFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())
        self.myManager.userFontChanged.emit(self._font_Size)
```

Comment: You could show your code, as well as what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc hey I aded example code! Thanks for looking in to it :- )

Comment: Please share a reproducible code.